# fork process under uwsgi, django

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I need to execute some slow tasks upon receiving a POST request.
My server runs under UWSGI which behaves in a weird manner

Localhost (`python manage.py runserver`):

- when receiving request from browser, I do `p = Process(target=workload); p.start(); return redirect(...)`. Browser immediately follows the redirect, and working process starts in the background.

UWSGI (2 workers):

- Background process starts, but Browser doesn't get redirected. It waits until the child exit.

Note, I have added `close-on-exec=true` (as advised in documentation and in [Running a subprocess in uwsgi application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592692/running-a-subprocess-in-uwsgi-application)) parameter in UWSGI configuration, but that has no visible effect, application waits for child's exit

Comment: Is that a `multiprocessing.Process()`?

Comment: yes, exactly that's it

Comment: Python in general is not very good at multiprocessing, did you consider using Celery to offload your web workers, or is it a no-no?

Comment: @jkoestinger i did consider, and will most likely do it. It requires interacting with Ops again, and that is slow...

Answer (score 0):

I imagine Python gets confused since the interpreter `multiprocessing.Process()` is defaulting to is the the `uwsgi` binary, not the regular Python interpreter.

Additionally, you may be using the `fork` spawn method (depending on OS) and forking the uWSGI worker isn't a great idea.

You will likely need to call [`multiprocessing.set_executable()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.set_executable) and `multiprocessing.set_spawn_method()` when you're running under uWSGI with something like this in e.g. your Django settings.py:

```
import multiprocessing
import sys

try:
    import uwsgi  # magic module only available when under uwsgi
except ImportError:
    uwsgi = None

if uwsgi:
    multiprocessing.set_spawn_method('spawn')
    multiprocessing.set_executable(os.path.join(sys.exec_prefix, 'python'))
```

However, you may want look into using e.g. [uWSGI's spooler system](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Spooler.html) or some other work queue/background task system such as Huey, rq, Minique, Celery, etc.

Comment: So now the browser gets redirected, but background process is not spawned :) I guess it's a dead end